# Complex MySQL left join query

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to write more complex/better mysql statements however I'm getting a bit tripped up on using logic to create the statement and am not completely sure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated!

Basically my goal statement is to Select all from the product table, and then for every product join an image where display = 1

```
        "SELECT p
          FROM CurbbedUserBundle:Product p
          LEFT JOIN CurbbedUserBundle:ProductImages i
          ON p.id = i.id
          WHERE i.display = 1
          ORDER BY p.name ASC"
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `left join`, then all the conditions on the second table should be in the `on` clause.  You need to move the condition in the `where` to the `on`:

```
SELECT p
FROM CurbbedUserBundle:Product p LEFT JOIN
     CurbbedUserBundle:ProductImages i
     ON p.id = i.id AND i.display = 1
ORDER BY p.name ASC
```

EDIT:

The rule for a left join is that it keeps all rows in the first table regardless of whether the `on` conditions is true or not.  Hence, if you want to filter by the first table, put the condition in the `where` clause.  It won't do anything in the `on`.  The rule for `right join` is exactly the opposite.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly in SequelPro!

If I can expand it a bit...
Where would I put something like "Where p.active = 1"

Comment: SELECT *
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN ProductImages
ON Product.id = ProductImages.id AND ProductImages.display = 1
WHERE Product.active = 1
ORDER BY Product.name ASC

Got it, 
Thanks again!

Comment: And a fantastic explanation to my second question, thank you very much!